# How do I find if a package is installed by default for each Ubuntu release?

Tags: package-management

I know how to check if a package is installed and if its available for install but I cannot find any list of packages that are installed with a release from Ubuntu.

Sometimes I am trying to answer something and I cannot remember if the tool I will refer was installed by default of if I installed in a later point and cant remember. What if its something I have and a user using another desktop environment does not?

I know I can recommend to install the package prior to asking him to use it but I would like to know if its installed by default or not.

Is there such list? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can.

With each release, there is something called a "manifest" of the ISO created - this lists all the installed packages, their versions, etc.

Examples:

- http://releases.ubuntu.com/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-i386.manifest
- http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.manifest
- http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.manifest
- http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.manifest
- http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.manifest
- http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.manifest

Newer releases are listed at http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Toppy! You made my day ;)

Comment: @BrunoPereira a pleasure. :)

Comment: 11.10 amd 64 = 1392 pkgs

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not the correct answer.  The .manifest file lists the packages on the live CD/DVD or USB stick which is not necessarily what's in a default install.  The .manifest file for 13.04 lists `gksu` and `gparted` both of these are on the install media; neither is exists in a clean install.  I don't have a better answer though.

Comment: Ok, yes, that is correct. it isn't entirely accurate, but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

Indirectly you could check Synaptic history of installation (In the File menu) type the name of your package you will know when it was installed or updated.

Comment: I don't want to do it in a system since when I am trying to tell someone "use this or that" I cannot have access to synaptic or my system all the time and I for sure don't have access to his system. Thanks for the answer anyways, +1.